# Windows 7 "lost" memory

Tags: windows-7, memory

I'm running Windows 7 Pro x64 with 4GB ram. The thing is, when I load up Star Wars: The old Republic, that program readily occupies around 1.5GB memory, according to task manager. In resource monitor, the private memory used is a bit lower, but still around 1GB. The only other application running is Chrome with a few tabs.

My question is now, why does this lead to me being completely out of memory and causing excessive harddisk thrashing?

Task manager lists my available memory as:

```
Total       4094
Cached        76
Available     77
Free           0
```

Resource monitor lists 0 as hardware reserved. Does Windows 7 + services really use 2.5GB memory? Or am I missing something completely obvious?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Open up Resource Monitor from task manager and have a look at the memory section. This will give you a much more detailed breakdown of the memory usage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The only other application running is Chrome with a few tabs.

Chrome can use between 50MB+ depending on how many tabs you have open.  How much memory exactly is Chrome using?

> Does Windows 7 + services really use 2.5GB memory? Or am I missing
>   something completely obvious?

You have other applications running.

Comment: 3 tabs in Chrome, ~280 MB memory according to chrome://memory-redirect/.

This still doesn't explain everything. Maybe Windows 7 is just more memory hungry than I would have thought.

Comment: I run Windows 7 in a VM with only 1GB of memory and it works, so it certainly don't take too much. You must have some memory hungry background programs like anti-virus running,

Comment: Only MSSE which really doesn't eat that much. Meh, at least it's a good reason for actually doing that upgrade I want :)

Comment: @Bjørn - While Windows 7 might use more memory then Windows XP for many reasons, it certainly doesn't use 2.5GB of memory, still have not told us what else is running.